# Embedding image in QWebView with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, qt, webkit, embed

I am writing a small application with Qt 4.6 (64-bit Arch Linux, though that shouldn't matter) which lets the user edit a document using a QWebView with contentEditable turned on.  However, for some reason embedding an image does not work.  Here is a code snippet:

```
void LeafEditView::onInsertImage()
{
    // bring up a dialog, ask for an image
    QString imagePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open Image File"),"/",tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));
    ui->leafEditor->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement().evaluateJavaScript("document.execCommand('insertImage',null,'"+imagePath+"');");
}
```

The test image does in fact exist and yet absolutely nothing happens.  Bold / italics / underline all work fine via JavaScript, just not images.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that WebKit has a policy of not loading resources from the local filesystem without some massaging. In my code, I have a WebKit view which I'm using to edit leaves in a notebook.  The following one-liner solved my issue:

```
 ui->leafEditor->page()->mainFrame()->setHtml("<html><head></head><body></body></html>",QUrl("file:///"));
```

From what I gleaned by lurking around the WebKit mailing list archives, in order to load files from the local filesystem one must set the URI to be file:, and this does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Check that `QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages` is enabled.

You could also try:
`document.execCommand('insertImage',false,'"+imagePath+"');`

Try using relative vs absolute paths to the image.

Last but not least, poke around [this](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/graphics-dojo/commit/c8d0c381b994d7417863832929cc4c3f710f2db5) sample application -- they are using a similar method of Javascript execCommand(), they do some things in a slightly different way such as using `QUrl::fromLocalFile`.

Best of luck!

Comment: I had tried a number of those things.  I poked around, then asked here, and continued poking around.  It increases the odds of an answer :)